# codeigniter ignoring part of search query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, search

I find myself having a problem with this particular codeigniter MySQL query.

Im trying to search my database rows where any of the 3 fields/columns contains the same phrase as the search string but the "status" must not be marked as "deleted"

I first tried:

```
$this->db->where('status !=', 'deleted');
$this->db->like('meta_title', $string);
$this->db->or_like('name', $string);
$this->db->or_like('text_full', $string);
```

But it just ignored the meta_title field completely, it wouldnt compare or look into "meta_title" at all. Then i tried the following based on someone else's stackexchange question and it fixed that problem but now it ignores:

```
WHERE `status` != 'deleted'
```

My code

```
$rows = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$string%' OR `meta_title` LIKE '%$string%' OR `slug` LIKE '%$string%' OR `text_full` LIKE '%$string%' AND `status` != 'deleted' ")->result_array();

var_dump($rows); 
echo $this->db->last_query(); die();
```

This returns all the rows, even the rows marked as deleted,

I also tried without the back ticks and i also tried

```
`status` NOT LIKE 'deleted'
```

Like this

```
$rows = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$string%' OR `meta_title` LIKE '%$string%' OR `slug` LIKE '%$string%' OR `text_full` LIKE '%$string%' AND `status` NOT LIKE 'deleted' ")->result_array();
```

The result of

```
echo $this->db->last_query(); die();
```

is:

```
SELECT * FROM `categories` WHERE `name` LIKE '%buyer%' OR `meta_title` LIKE '%buyer%' OR `slug` LIKE '%buyer%' OR `text_full` LIKE '%buyer%' AND `status` != 'deleted'
```

Ive also tried placing WHERE `status` != 'deleted' in the beginning of the query

Im not very proficient in web dev but i have played around a bit with this problem, unfortunately ive reached the point where i need help to understand what im doing wrong.

Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have the `OR` operator in a SQL predicate things get goofy. Essentially, your statement says,

> "I want rows that are not deleted - OR - rows that match my other conditions."

You need to wrap the optional conditions in parenthesis to separate them from the conditions required on all rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `categories` 
WHERE `status` != 'deleted'
AND (`meta_title` LIKE '%$string%' 
      OR `slug` LIKE '%$string%' 
      OR `text_full` LIKE '%$string%'
      OR `name` LIKE '%$string%');
```

Comment: my apologies, i wasnt sure how